# Unexpected token ILLEGAL, even on clean install - jquery-issue?

Tags: php, jquery, linux

update i get even more issues and errors;

```
POST http://literaturen.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

200 OK
        1,39s   
jquery...=1.11.0 (Zeile 4)
GET http://fls-eu.amazon.de/1/batch/1/OE/A1PA6795UKM...26pc0%3D831%26ld0%3D831%26t0%3D1399322099520:831

204 No Content
        197ms   
csm-ba..._V1_.js (Zeile 232)
Content Security Policy: Ungültige Quelle chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl kann nicht verarbeitet werden
Content Security Policy: Unbekannte Quelle chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl konnte nicht verarbeitet werden

Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the 
App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

ping?c...dk=joey (Zeile 1)
```

and the following errors:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character

!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports

    load-s...ver=3.9 (Zeile 2, Spalte 15)
SyntaxError: illegal character

...c,d){var f;return f=c&&c.hasOwnProperty(\"constructor\")?c.constructor:function(...

load-s...ver=3.9 (Zeile 1, Spalte 60)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

})( jQuery );

customize.php (Zeile 560)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

jQuery(document).ready(function()
```

**note:** i do not know why i do get all those nasty errrors.

I've been working on a new project with wordpress. However, I start noticing that some features on the back office (like slide down menus and widgets) weren't working. So I fired up debugging console of my browser and found that there is an intermittent issue:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL load-scripts.php:1
>   load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery,utils,json2&ver=xyz other
>   times...

to be frank: I had issues

> Uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal
>
> was not able to do configurations of the widgets in wp 3.9 was not
>   able to access the set-options page was not able to switch the
>   accessible mode

btw .- see [the page](http://www.literaturen.org) - a non profit page: it is BETA-BETA

**btw** - the `magic_quotes_gpc`, `magic_quotes_runtime`, are not set off
do you think that this may help.

WHAT I WAS INVESTIGATIN SO FAR:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL load-scripts.php:1
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined load-scripts.php:2
>
> (anonymous function)

Similar issues found in different browsers: Chrome, Safari and Firefox.
Next step was googling for some answers and found a reference for javascript diagnose here. When I enable `SCRIPT_DEBUG`, the error stops, and everything runs smoothly again.

At this moment I don't have some plugin nor theme installed and been running in localhost.

Couldn't find yet a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: This ___is not___ Java. It is Javascript. The two are very very different.

Comment: Do you have any "security" plugins activated? Do you have anything in the /wp-admin/.htaccess file (the file normally should not exist, some plugins create it). Do you have anything unusual in the normal .htaccess file?

Comment: hi - thanks for the quick answer - no securityplugins are acitivated. i will check the htaccess-things later

Comment: What happens if you disable all your chrome extensions? I don't get those errors here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're trying to utilize jQuery in custom code, but haven't actually enqueue'd the jQuery script - This line gives it away (I think?):

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

if you are using [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to bring in a custom `.js` file, make sure you set `jquery` as a dependancy

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myfile.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Comment: hello dear eric many thanks; i will try to understand all your ideas & thoughts. i come back later for more descriptions and explanations.  meanwhile - all the best to  you!!